# How to disable UIPopoverController animation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, uipopovercontroller, ios-simulator

I have added the popOvercontroller on click of navigation bar right button.i don't want the animation effect..can anybody tell me how to disable it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you instantiate it? the docuemntation mentions  `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` - sounds like the perfect answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

There are two pieces to this.  Using presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:NO or presentPopoverFromRect:permittedArrowDirections:animated:NO to present the popover will prevent the "appearing" animation.  To disable the disable the "disappearing" I had to add this to the delegate:

```
- (BOOL) popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popover {
    // Any cleanup code (popoverControllerDidDismissPopover won't be called)

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding "ShouldDimissPopover" as I needed to remove animation from the dismiss operation.

Answer (score 0):

Btw. if you're showing a popover from a table view, you'll want to animate row deselection at the same time while popover is being dismissed. To achieve this, you can use:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popover {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```